# Having Trouble Showing New Assets

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

So, when I was changing the assets throughout my application, for some odd reason, when I build my application some old versions of image assets are incorrectly used throughout my application. They are not even present anywhere within the application's directory.

Note: These image assets had used the same names as the old versions.

EDIT: This is only the behavior for images used for the "selected" states of buttons throughout my app.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Check in derived data folder of your project - accessible from organizer.

2 - Check your iOS simulator folder (`~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/Username/`) for your app and see what version of images it shows. Reset iOS simulator and launch your app again.

3 - Restart XCode.